# what is the full form of MCE in TinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce

Can anyone Explain what is the full form of MCE in TinyMCE?

```
tinymce.init({
                selector: '#procedDtlsOfSelTestInTestDlgSelGridIms',
                browser_spellcheck: true,
                contextmenu: false,
                //                toolbar: true
                menubar: false
            });
```